# how would i load themes from parent domain onto a subdomain with smarty?

Tags: php, subdomain, smarty

I have a default themes folder on my parent domain such as `foo.bar/themes/default/`

when a user registers i make a sub domain for them like `bob.foo.bar` how can I logically point to the default themes folder on my parent domain? My idea is that if they choose to have a custom theme for that theme to be uploaded to their sub domain folder and then have smarty point to it.

I know how to do this IF and only IF I have control over sub domain via PHP. But right now in cPanel when a sub domain is made it makes the vhosts files so that it goes directly to their document_root bypassing any of my PHP scripts that would control how the smarty theme paths are handled.

What would be a good solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if its a linux system, you could just make a script that creates links to the default theme.

```
foreach(scandrir($domain_path) as $domain_name)
{
    if(substr($domain, -8) == '.foo.bar')
    {
        if(!file_exists("{$domain_path}{$domain_name}/themes/default"))
        {
           exec("ln -s {$domain_path}foo.bar/themes/default {$domain_path}{$domain_name}/themes/default");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ah i see, you just made a "shortcut" i never thought of that!

Comment: just to be clear $domain_path would be set out side of the foreach loop right?

Comment: yes, at my server it whould be /mnt/data/www/, you didn't left any clue about what it was on your server, so i just skiped that part

Comment: oh well i didn't think it was needed my server has a path of `/home/hosts/public_html/` for the default location and `/home/hosts/public_html/users/` for the subdomains

Comment: oh, never seent that structure before, im use to have only users in my /home/, my i ask what distro you running? im running gentoo myself

Comment: i'm running CentOS 5.6, but yes your right. That is a custom structure I made for my web service.